# Figma Search Plugin

Tags: user-interface, plugins, user-experience, figma

Is there a plugin or a way in Figma where you can find how many components and styles are used in a design file? I'd love something that we could run that would give me the numbers I'm looking to collect without having to manually open every file, navigate through every page within the file, then open the library info and write down the number of components and styles used and if the library was actually enabled or not

Comment: Currently there is no way of doing that natively in Figma. You could write a plugin/widget to do that. Here is a setup guide to get started with making plugin in Figma https://www.figma.com/plugin-docs/setup/

Answer (score 0):

There is a native way of getting a report of component usage in Figma, but it requires you to have an Organization License. And an admin role.

In the Home Tab, click Admin Settings → Resources → Libraries

It's so good, because it also reports how many time a component has been detached,

[image]